# My websites is hacked and IP is on a Spam Blacklist

Tags: wordpress, list, spam

I created a wordpress blog few months ago and left updating it, because i was busy in other things. Today when i tried to log in to my wordpress i received a message
Your IP is on a Spam Blacklist.

When i visited my blog i saw a anchor text link right under my logo and i never put it there.

Screenshot: http://i62.tinypic.com/2lddap2.png

Now i can't log in to my WordPress and my Ip is added to spam list.

I,m worried, what should i do to remove the anchor text link and to clear the spam allegation. Your help will be highly appreciated thanks in advance and sorry for bearing my bad English.

My blog: trueinfoforyou(.)com

Comment: I cannot see the link there.  Perhaps you have an adware infection on your browser

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest getting the support e-mail off of the host providing your WordPress site, either yourself if possible or through another means. Once you've got it, contact them and just explain the situation. I'm sure once you've explained it they'll be happy to resolve the problems you're facing; as at the end of the day, it's commonplace for things like this to occur nowadays.

No host wants to lose business. I'm positive they'll be happy to oblige in removing you from any blacklist.